# Java - Generics; Is it usefull to parameterize a method if you want to swap 2 Items of an object?

Tags: java, generics, generic-method

The following code alows to swap 2 Items of an Object :

```
public class Box<F, S> {
    F first;
    S second;   

    //Method to swap
    public static <F> void swapItems(Box<F,F> box){

        F temp = box.first;
        box.first = box.second;
        box.second = temp;
    }
}

//The method could also be implemented like this:

    void swapItems() {

        F tmp1 = first;
        S tmp2 = second;
        first = (F) tmp2;
        second = (S) tmp1;
    }
```

What is the advantage of the generic code? I just don't get it. 
Could sombody explain this to me? Might the generic one be useful if i call this method on 2 objects?

Comment: What if the type of F and S are different?

Comment: If S would be a subclass of F it works (Number & Integer for example). 
If the types are diffrent i.e. Integer and String it would'nt work.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  You have a `Box`.  You shouldn't care what order the items are in.  You should be able to pull the item you care about out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example class is in fact a good example of bad use of generics. A generic `Box` used to swap items is founded on a misconception.

> Might the generic one be useful if i call this method on 2 objects?

That's right (with the code in the question). Generics aren't designed for code reuse or for structuring code. We have methods, packages, and modules for that.

A box of two items that supports swapping order, may be implemented better as follows (although a better-suited name would be `Pair`, I believe):

```
class Box<T> {
    private T first;
    private T second;   

    //2-parameter constructor

    public void swapItems(){

        T temp = first;
        first = second;
        second = temp;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

The above class could be used as follows:

```
Box<String> stringBox = new Box<>("first", "second");
String first = stringBox.getFirst();
String second = stringBox.getSecond();
```

Or as follows:

```
Box<Integer> intBox = new Box<>(1, 2);
int first = intBox.getFirst();
int second = intBox.getSecond();
```

> What is the advantage of the generic code?

Assuming you had a class as the one above, then generics would allow you to make a box of different types `<T>`, with type-safety guaranteed by the compiler, just as shown in the two example uses: the `Box` class is defined once, but used with "box items" of different types, of which the compiler is aware and for which it helps validate types.

For example, the following incorrect calls would fail (continuing examples above):

```
String third = intBox.getFirst();
```

This last (incorrect) statement will fail at compile time, thus enabling faster feedback (as opposed to class cast exceptions at runtime).

Other important notes:

- Your class declares two distinct type parameters, `<F, S>`, so you cannot "swap" `first` and `second`. The compiler would reject the code as the two types aren't guaranteed to be compatible.

Answer (score 1):

> The method could also be implemented like this:

No it couldn't. If you swap `Box<F, S>` you would get `Box<S, F>`, a different type. With an instance method, you can't just magically change the type of the object on which it is called!

A static method that changes `Box<F,S>` to `Box<S, F>` could be something like this:

```
public static <F, S> Box<S, F> swapItems(Box<F,S> box){

    Box<S, F> newBox = new Box<>();
    newBox.first = box.second;
    newBox.second = box.first;
    return newBox;
}

// usage:
Box<Integer, String> newBox = Box.swapItems(someBox);
```

An instance method is still possible to  write, but you need to return a new box instead of changing the state of `this`.

```
public Box<S, F> itemsSwapped(){

    Box<S, F> newBox = new Box<>();
    newBox.first = this.second;
    newBox.second = this.first;
    return newBox;
}

// usage:
Box<Integer, String> newBox = someBox.itemsSwapped();
```

Comment: In your example: Is one of the 2 methods more useful than the other one? Why?

Comment: @Smith You call them differently. See the edit. I prefer the second one. You can choose whichever you think is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This actually won't even compile, in many cases. For a more concrete example, say your type F is a String, and your type S is an Integer. Then, you'd end up with a swapItems method like this:

```
public void swapItems(){
    String first = "foo";
    Integer second = 2;
    String tmp1 = first;
    Integer tmp2 = second;
    first = (String) tmp2;
    second = (Integer) tmp1;
}
```

The compiler will complain: "Inconvertible types; cannot cast java.lang.Integer to java.lang.String".